# LWC datatable does not refresh its view

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

so I'm relatively new to lightning web components and still not understanding all of the eventhandling. I'm creating a component for a customer and I'm having some problems with my lightning-datatable.

i have a parent-child structure like this

**parent.html**

```
<c-custom-data-table table-data={tableData}></c-custom-data-table>
```

**parent.js**

```
export default class fastOrder extends LightningElement {
    @track tableData = [];
    localTable = [];

    setRowData(event) {
        this.localTable.push(event.detail);
        this.tableData = this.localTable;
        this.template.querySelector('c-custom-data-table').setTableData(this.tableData);
    }
}
```

**child.html**

```
<lightning-datatable              
                key-field="Produktcode__c"
                data={tableData}
                columns={columns}
                onrowselection={getSelectedRecords}>
        </lightning-datatable>
```

**child.js**

```
export default class BasicDatatable extends LightningElement {
    @track columns = columns;
    @track tableData = [];

    @api setTableData(detail) {
        this.tableData = detail; 
    }
}
```

Im calling `setRowData(event)` from another child-component in the context of an event. The first time I'm doing this the view of the datatable is refreshed after the `tableData` property gets updated. But every other time than the first one theres no refresh of the view. according to the console the `tableData` property gets properly updated but i dont see any new rows in my datatable.

I also tried changing the binding to @api with getter and setter

```
@track _tableData = [];
    @api 
    get tableData() {
        return this._tableData;
    }
    set tableData(value) {
        this._tableData = value;
    }
```

with exactly the same effect.

Am I missing something here? I saw examples with @track binding which got constantly refreshed with the update of the tracked property. I searched and tried for hours but maybe someone already encountered this kind of situation and can help me with a workaround (or atleast an explanation).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not need to set the dataTable-property explicitly in your child. If parent.dataTable gets updated, then child.dataTable will be automatically updated, and then the lightning-datatable will be refreshed. You don't have to use the query-selector, nor child.setTable(). @track does it for you. Simply set parent.tableData, remove the query-selector-call and it should work.

Comment: Addition: The tableData-property in your child must be annotated with @api, so that you can set it in your parent via <c-custom-data-table table-data={tableData}>

Comment: I updated my code as suggested and used the solution that @BritishBoyinDC linked and it worked! thank your very much :)

Comment: The combination of both suggestions was the solution, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think this is the same issue outlined [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253717/how-to-convey-lwcs-complex-reactive-property-back-to-markup)

Basically, using push does not have the affect of triggering a re-render. The best option is to use the accepted solution outlined in the link - re-create the array using the ES6 spread operator, which will cause the component to view it as a new array