# Unable to get the data in columns using lightning data table with imperative call and javascript

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html, data, column

I am new to salesforce, I am trying to learn lightning datatable with imperative call in salesforce.
I am unable to get the data in the column, its not throwing any error though. Please help to fix it.
Below is the code:

'''
HTML Code:

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
    key-field="Id"
    data={result}
    columns={columns}></lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

'''
Javascript:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getData';

const columns = [
    { label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'FirstName' },
    //{ label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'LastName' },
    //{ label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email' },
];

export default class DataTableWithImperativeCall extends LightningElement {
    @track result=[];
    @track columns = columns;
    connectedCallback() {
        this.getResults();
    }

    getResults() {
        getContactList()
            .then(cdata => {
                //console.log(cdata);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(cdata));
                let finalData=[];
                for(var i=0;i<cdata.length;i++)
                {
                    finalData.push(cdata[i].FirstName);
                }
                this.result=finalData;
                //console.log('results'+JSON.stringify(this.result));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.errors = error;
            });

    }
}
```

'''
Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<contact> getData()
    {
        return [select id,firstName,LastName,email from contact order by firstName asc nulls last limit 10];
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: Please find the html code below, as its not showing up for me in the body-           <template>
    <lightning-datatable
    key-field="Id"
    data={result}
    columns={columns}></lightning-datatable>
</template>

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format your code. You can wrap each code block in ``` (triple backticks, on a line by themselves) to do this. You can make an [edit] to update your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LWC Datatable pushing data to array using `push` method does not trigger any change in UI. You will have to reassign the data to array with `=` operator.

```
let finalData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cdata.length; i++) {
    finalData.push(cdata[i].FirstName);
}
this.result = finalData;
```

To know more on this please check [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253717/how-to-convey-lwcs-complex-reactive-property-back-to-markup)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nagendra, I have modified the code as you suggested but it fixed half of the problem. I am now getting empty rows displayed but no data in it. Not sure what is causing this.

Comment: can you please update your code above in your question, also a sample of `cdata` would help. Also make sure your object key matches the label name you specified.

Comment: I have added the updated code in the question, also checked the label name which is matching with object key. Thank you.

Comment: My code was just an example,  you will still need to build a list of object in js, and each object with a property as `FirstName`

Comment: i.e. change `finalData.push(cdata[i].FirstName);` to `finalData.push(cdata[i]);`

Comment: Thanks Nagendra, I am able to fix the problem. I have added the code and able to get the data on the UI. Thanks for your suggestions.{
                    finalData.push({FirstName:cdata[i].FirstName,LastName:cdata[i].LastName,Email:cdata[i].Email});
                }